# When using randomize transform => randomize scale, how do you have the randomized values all be above zero?

Tags: transforms, scale

I'm trying to Randomize Scale(only Z) of some identical boxes, the goal being to have all of their bottom faces on the same level, while top faces are on different heights.

As you can see below, some of the boxes have their Z randomized to negative values.
[image]

I know Blender accepts some simple maths when entering values, so I tried entering |6.24| (as an absolute value) to see if that will work, but no luck.

*So, I'd like to know if there's a smarter way to go about this, maybe without Randomize Transform tool altogether.*

Also, I'd like to know if there IS a way to use some equivalent of |x| in Blender, or is there no such feature?

**Thank you for your time!**

Comment: In addition to an actual answer, note that Blender's math operations apply to what you are typing into the field, they are not evaluated in context. So the hypothetical `|6.24|` would not work for what you want, since it would evaluate to `6.24` which is the same as if you just typed `6.24` into the field directly.

Comment: Note that you can use `abs(value)` to get the positive of `value`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Blender **2.92**, you can use the new *Geometry Nodes* to place boxes randomly with random heights. The *Attribute Randomize* node lets you define a minimum and a maximum value for the scale. [image: blocks on a plane with geometry nodes]

Answer (score 4):

Just randomize them like you did. Then add an empty and parent all cubes to it.

Then move the empty up (z-Axis) as much as you need it.